# Inequality Surrounding Subsets

Tags: graph-theory

Let $A$ be a finite set with subsets $A_1,...,A_n,$ and let $d_1...,d_n \in
\mathbb{N}$. I want to show that if there are disjoint subsets
$D_k \subseteq A_k, |D_k| = d_k$ for all $k \leq n$ if and only if
$$\left|\cup_{i \in I} A_i\right| \geq \sum_{i \in I} d_i, I \subseteq [n].$$

I was considering forming this problem using Hall's Condition, although I think
I might need help with generating the bipartition. Take $B = \{A_1,...,A_n\}$
and $C = \bigcup_{i \in I} D_i$. I was considering developing a bipartition
such that there is an edge connected between the two sets if $d \in A_i.$

However, I am having some difficulty trying to induce this to follow the
behavor of Hall's condition. Any recommendations on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you know how to prove the "only if" direction, so your question is about how to prove the "if". And I suppose you know how to prove the result in case $d_i=1$ for all $i.$

**Hint.** Replace the sequence $A_1,\dots,A_n$ by a sequence of sets of length $d_1+\cdots+d_n$ in which each of the original sets $A_i$ is repeated $d_i$ times. Apply Hall's theorem to the new sequence.